# FirebaseMessagingService onreceivemessage() not being called

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've migrated from GCM to FCM on my app,

now i'm having trouble receiving FCM .

I used the firebase assistant, connected the app to firebase okay and used this dependency

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2'
}
```

AndroidManifest :

```
       <service android:name="com.galcomm.mobik.Service.FCMTokenRefreshListenerService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="com.galcomm.mobik.Service.FCMPushReceiverService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

The RefreshToken service :

```
public class FCMTokenRefreshListenerService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

//If the token is changed registering the device again
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d("fcm", "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}

private void sendRegistrationToServer(String refreshedToken) {
    Log.e("FCMTOKEN : ",refreshedToken);

}
}
```

and the FirebaseMessaging Service

```
public class FCMPushReceiverService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message){
    String from = message.getFrom();
    Log.e("FCMTOKEN ","NMSG_REC : "+from);
    String title = message.getNotification().getTitle();
    String body = message.getNotification().getBody();
    Map data = message.getData();
    sendNotification(from, data);
}}
```

Now I get the token okay but when i try it on the Firebase console test notification it says complete but it doesn't go to `OnMessageReceived` or puts a Notification, I tried both with Data payload and without like other questions suggested but that wasn't it.

EDIT :

When i try to send it it says Completed but the next time i try the same token it says InvalidToken both on firebase console and in [pushtry.com](http://pushtry.com)

Edit 2:

I found an error on logcat when i'm trying to send an fcm :

```
broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE
```

What am I missing here ?

any help will be good, Thanks in advance

Comment: Make sure you are using correct token ! And are you getting "Completed" status for that message ?

Comment: yes , device token is ok and i get completed in the console